# Collect data from third party facebook application

Tags: java, facebook, canvas

Maybe its a newbie question but I need some info for what I have in mind.

Is it possible to get any kind of data (e.g. text) from a third-party app in facebook?

I checked that facebook apps run within a wrapper called canvas. How can I collect text that appears inside this canvas (after of course I have logged in with an account and run the 3rd-party app)?

I want to write a desktop app that keeps log of the data changes appearing inside the wrapper (the 3rd-party app updates a list every 30 secs).

Thx in advance!

Comment: Do you want to scrape data off from a third party app within Facebook?

Comment: Are you thinking anything like Wayback machine http://archive.org/web/web.php ?

Comment: @AnveshSaxena Thats right! "Web scraping" is I think the right term for want I want to do. I can now do a bit of a research on the topic. Thanks!

Comment: @Vijay I am aware of Wayback Machine but I dont know how thats gonna help.. The output of the 3rd-party app are statistics about the specific facebook user and not public content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For retrieving or saving the content you can use any of Web scraping tools like [Visual Web Ripper](http://www.visualwebripper.com/).. Though I would suggest you also keep an eye for the data use policy and copyright issues...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm gonna give it a try along with other scraping tools and check which output serves me best. I'm intending to keep the outcome of this project for private use for the time being so I dont worry about the policies. 
I appreciate the answer but I'll keep this open for any other ideas that may not have passed through our minds.

Comment: After you are done with your research, I would appreciate if you could share the tools you used up here.

Comment: The latest version of Visual Web Ripper works wonders so far! It exports the list the way I want to excel and supports small time internals so I can get the updates right. I could base my project on its output but the problem is its too damn expensive to keep using it after the trial..!

Comment: Yes, that is one thing....that is why I wanted to know if you come across another tool of this kind please share it..meanwhile I would too look at alternatives